# strange error in production for papperclip, Cocaine::ExitStatusError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I got this error in airbrake at production: (I just uploaded a version with an upgrade of both rails and ruby, to 1.9.3 and 3.2)

```
Cocaine::ExitStatusError: Command 'convert /tmp/photo (1)20130424-3742-dohg6e.JPG -auto-orient /tmp/20130424-3742-eiksvr' returned 2. Expected 0 Here is the command output:
```

my paperclip code:

```
has_attached_file :photo,
                :styles => {:original => "1024x1024>", :large => '800x600>', :thumb => '120x72#'},
                :convert_options => {:original => '-strip -quality 90', :large => '-strip -quality 90', :thumb => '-strip'},
                :processors => [:auto_orient, :thumbnail],
                :url => "/system/statuses/:id_partition/:style.:extension",
                :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:id_partition/:style.:extension"
```

what does this error mean? and how can i handle it?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm no entirely sure. But it seems that your production server doesn't have the ImageMagick library installed properly.

cocaine is a library for executing commnad tools.. I believe that it is trying to call some imagemagick command and returning somekind of error

Comment: OK so i tried to upgrade imagemagick and this is what I got:
sudo apt-get install imagemagick --fix-missing 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
imagemagick is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 83 not upgraded.

Comment: hm... really strange.. if it isn't working on production with the same settings I would investigate the gem itself. and see in what circumstances causes that crash. if It's not a problem for you I would even move to carrierwave. I used paperclip before, but now my projects are 100% carrierwave.

Answer (score 0):

Paperclip rescue's any Cocaine error, including things like Segmentation Faults in ImageMagick.  It returns a `''` i.e. an empty string. [Line 27](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/geometry_detector_factory.rb#L27) of geometry dector factory.